# Apple OSX Script Editor - Photos Suite function make in javascript

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, apple-photos

Does anyone knows how to use the javascript functions of the Photo Suite in Apple's OSX script editor? The documentation is really bad or I do not understand the way of using it.

**Doc description:**

> **`make`** method : Create a new object. Only new albums and folders can be created.
>   **`make`**
>   **`new`**: type : The class of the new object, allowed values are album or folder
>   [**`named`**: text ] : The name of the new object.
>   [**`at`**: Folder ] : The parent folder for the new object.
>       **`→`** Album or Folder : The new object.

**My code:**

```
nameOfAlbumForPhotosWithoutAlbum="PhotosWithoutAlbum"
```

I tried the following, however none worked:

```
albumForPhotosWithoutAlbum=photos.make(album,nameOfAlbumForPhotosWithoutAlbum)
albumForPhotosWithoutAlbum=photos.make(photos.album,nameOfAlbumForPhotosWithoutAlbum)
albumForPhotosWithoutAlbum=photos.make(photos.album.type,nameOfAlbumForPhotosWithoutAlbum)
```

After reading the manual again, I tried the following, again without success. It returns: `Can't find variable: Album`. The same happens to lower case. I tried `typeof`, but I do not know how to get the type of the class Album.

```
albumForPhotosWithoutAlbum=photos.make({new:Album.name,named:"TestFolder"})
```

Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript for Automation is half-baked and buggy, and documentation and community are virtually non-existent. Apple abandoned it pretty much as soon as it went out the door. I suggest you stick to AppleScript—the language is lousy, but at least the automation stuff works right and you can always find other users to help.

Comment: I totally agree, so actually stackoverflow is my last idea to find out how it may work. The documentation is really terrible and I decided to not learn Applescript at all, for a onetime shot script I need. But at all, you are right.